KVM causing system to hang
Running 24.0.4.1 with all latest updates. After applying the last updates none of mv VM's will start in kvm. I just rebuilt the system applied all the same updates and same issue. As soon as I begin installation the system locks up hard.
Clean install and no other services but kvm. Using Bridge interface to connectivity. Don't even know where to start looking. I went to dmesg and all I see that I think matters is the split_lock message but it happens at boot. I disabled split_lock via sysctl kernel.split_lock_mitigate=0 and had the same result.
Please help
Thanks Michael

CPU is Intel i9-11900H 16 core
64Gb of Ram and 4TB SSD GMKTec M4

Please add additional or requested info to your original posting.  No problem with my i7 11800h running kvm. What exact command do you use to invoke kvm? My dmesg output is: 0.000000] x86/split lock detection: #AC: crashing the kernel on kernel split_locks and warning on user-space split_locks (default setting).

I am using VM Manager from another ubuntu desktop on a. separate machine on the same network. That machine is also running 24..4 and all packages are up to date. I have not tried from cli.
Is there more information that would be helpful? I have tried multiple vm's and the result is the same.

It might be possible to run virt-manager(?) from a terminal and get the actual output of what it is doing.  Only did it once for a Windows install to see what the 24h2 tpm business was doing (it was much more complicated than my manual efforts). From a terminal I run: kvm -smp cores=4,threads=2 -cpu host -m 4096 -vga virtio -usb $IMAGE

Ok I tried and from the command line the system hangs right after
Starting Install
Allocating 'myvm.img'
Could something be wrong with my ssd?
I don't have issues elsewhere with this system
I also looked in the /var/logs/libvirt directory and it's subdirectories and there was one file but it was 0 bytes.
Is there somewhere else I could look for a log message?

I just checked and it did create my.img file for the VM so must be right after allocating the image. I did copy the .iso image right to the images directory to make sure it was not some permissions problem.

Manually create the img: qemu-img create ${NAME}.img -f qcow2 ${VMSIZE}G   and install the ISO:  kvm -m 4096 -cpu host -cdrom $ISO -boot d ${NAME}.img  Maybe a fsck and smartctl (from smartmontools) is in order.

Hi I tried that and as soon as I hit enter the system fan went high for a minute and the machine froze. I ran an internal bios checker on the disk and it found nothing. I could get fsck to run on the /var/lib/libvirt
I am at a total loss. Going to reinstall with 22 instead and see if it is any different.
Nothing in /var/crash and could not find any log files that had information once the build started.

Final comment - turned out to be a HW issue with the motherboard. I tried multiple OS versions, swapped out memory and SSD but all had the same effect as soon as any virtualization kicked in the box would lock up. Replaced the motherboard and CPU and now no issues.
This is also why I will never get into a fully self driving automobile with no one in the front seat.
Thank you @ubfan1 for the suggestions and help.
